# Class 'viewController' has no initializers AND 'CurrentState' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers

Tags: swift

Why am I getting these 2 errors?

> "Class 'viewController' has no initializers"

and

> "'CurrentState' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible
>   initializers".

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import AVFoundation


let minFramesForFilterToSettle = 10

enum CurrentState {
case statePaused
case stateSampling
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

let session = AVCaptureSession()
var camera : AVCaptureDevice?
var validFrameCounter: Int = 0
var pulseDetector: PulseDetector
var filter: Filter
var currentState = CurrentState()       // init error

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.pulseDetector = PulseDetector()
    self.filter = Filter()
    // TO DO startCameraCapture() // call to un-used function. TO DO create function
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CurrentState` is an enumeration, so

```
var currentState = CurrentState()       // init error
```

should be (for example)

```
var currentState = CurrentState.statePaused
```

And the properties

```
var pulseDetector: PulseDetector
var filter: Filter
```

have no initial values. Either you change that to something like
(I don't know these types, therefore I cannot say which is a correct
initialization):

```
var pulseDetector = PulseDetector()
var filter = Filter()
```

or you override each designated initializer method to assign
initial values, or you declare them as (perhaps implicitly unwrapped)
optionals:

```
var pulseDetector: PulseDetector!
var filter: Filter!
```

Comment: Cool because I tried `var currentState = CurrentState.stateSampling`  with Code Sense and it worked so your answer confirms it. PulseDetector and Filter are classes. I was told in my last SO question to declare `var pulseDetector: PulseDetector` and 
    `var filter: Filter` and then init them in viewDidLoad as `self.pulseDetector = PulseDetector()`
 and `self.filter = Filter()`. (Just like my code). So this is not correct?

Comment: You can see those 2 classes here: http://i.imgur.com/Y1CANFS.png. What do you think is best in my situation?

Comment: I just went ahead and unwrapped them. But if you can think of something better please tell me. Answer marked as correct. Thank you.